# Unusual form's appearance after calling TCustomForm.SetFocusedControl function

Tags: delphi

First of all, my goal isn't that to set the focus on a control but I'm trying to understand why a form has a different appearance after deactivating and reactivating it.

[Here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.SetFocusedControl) is TCustomForm.SetFocusedControl function's description:

> Sets focus to a control on the form.
>
> Use **SetFocusedControl** to give a control on the form input focus. **SetFocusedControl** returns false if the Control specified by the Control parameter was already in the process of receiving focus, true otherwise.
>
> **Note:** A return value of true does not indicate the control has successfully received input focus. If the Control can't have focus (for example, if it is not visible), **SetFocusedControl** will still return true, indicating that an attempt was made.

I've created a simple test application in order to reproduce the observed behavior:

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Res : Boolean;
begin
  Res := Self.SetFocusedControl(Edit2);
  if(Self.ActiveControl <> nil) then
  begin
    Memo1.Text :=
      'ActiveControl is ' + Self.ActiveControl.Name + sLineBreak +
      'SetFocusedControl result is ' + BoolToStr(Res, True);
  end;
end;
```

---

Here are steps I followed to reproduce that behavior:

**1)** At start, the form appears as follows:

[image]

---

**2)** After clicking on "Button1", this is what I can see:

[image]

Memo1.Text reports that Edit2 is the active control but it hasn't the tipical focused appearance (selection and cursor).

Form's caption isn't grayed and clicking on it doesn't cause any change.

---

**3)** I've clicked outside the form (on the windows taskbar).

[image]

Form's caption became grayed.

---

**4)** I've reactivated the form by clicking on its caption:

[image]

Edit2 now looks like it has focus.

Could someone explain the differences between the form at point **2** and at point **4**? In both cases, Edit2 was the active control and I can't understand that appearance difference.

**Further informations:**

Tested on Delphi 2007, Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Why are you calling this function at all? I though we agreed that you aren't meant to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite what the documentation says, `TForm.SetFocusedControl()` does not actually set input focus onto `Edit2` (the Win32 [`SetFocus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646312.aspx) function is not called).  `Button1` receives the input focus when clicked on, and remains in focus after `SetFocusControl()` is called.  That is why `Edit2` does not render as focused.  If you want to move input focus to `Edit2`, call `Edit2.SetFocus()` instead of `Self.SetFocusedControl(Edit2)`.

However, calling `SetFocusedControl()` does change the VCL's internal state.  It sets the Form's `ActiveControl` and `FocusedControl` properties, and it sets the global `Screen` object's `ActiveControl`, `ActiveCustomForm`, `ActiveForm`, and `FocusedForm` propeties and reorders the entries of its `CustomForms` and `Forms` properties.

When the Form is deactivated and then reactivated, the VCL sets input focus to the last known "focused" control, which is now `Edit2` instead of `Button1`.